# How to use CyanogenMod Camera

Tags: cyanogenmod, camera

I have been using CyanogenMod Camera for a while. But my latest automatic update installed a new version of it. That wouldn't be a problem, except that I can't find any instructions on how to use it. Its behavior has changed.

The obvious searches (CyanogenMod camera help, CyanogenMod camera instructions) only come up with installation instructions not usage instructions.  Maybe the way to use this program is obvious to everyone else, but it isn't obvious to me.

Comment: I'm using Camera on a Motorola Moto E 2nd Generation running CyanogenMod 13.0-20161122-NIGHTLY-surniaunder Android.

Answer (score 2):

Are you referring to [LineageOS](https://lineageos.org/)? CyanogenMod is no longer in active development. I don't know what device you are using, but if you can, you should upgrade.

Anyway, the default camera application for LineageOS is Snap ([source](https://github.com/LineageOS/android_packages_apps_Snap)). You should be able to see it in your launcher as **Camera**.

[image: Camera in Lawnchair]

Comment: @paul I can't reply to your comment as my reputation is too low, but you should definitely upgrade. I see LineageOS 15.1 (unofficial) for `surnia` on [XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-e-2015/development/rom-unofficial-lineageos-15-0-t3669380). You may be in luck, since it looks like it may become officially supported soon!

Comment: I didn't think I was running Lineage  -- I thought I was running stock Motorola Android converted to CyanogenMod.  Has the stock Android system been converted to LineageOS?  I had never heard of LineageOS before seeing it referenced in this thread.